# Create facebook live streaming

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used the Facebook Graph API explorer try to create a live video. I used the HTTP POST request to "/me/live_videos" to create a live video but it response me error "(#100) No permission to perform current operation". I am sure my access_token have "publish_actions" and "user_videos" permissions. Did anyone have the same problem?

Comment: How are you making the HTTP request and which access token are you using? Did you generate the access token using graph API explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I also get this problem.now I may be solve this problem. If you generated the access_token by the Garph Api Explorer,you would meet the error.You can try to create an application, then use it to generate a access_token,and you will get the response.just like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltNcq.png)